# Can't run Carrot2 Document Clustering Workbench for 64-bit Linux (version 3.9.4) on my Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, carrot2

I've downloaded [Carrot2 Document Clustering Workbench for 64-bit Linux version 3.9.4](http://project.carrot2.org/download-workbench-linux-64bit.html) and tried to run it on my Ubuntu GNU/Linux 14.04.

First I've received an error:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]
```

Then I've installed the following, hoping to fix the error above:

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

Then I tried to run the workbench again but this time I've received:

```
$ carrot2-workbench-3.9.4/carrot2-workbench 

2015-01-30 12:14:57,545 INFO  org.carrot2.workbench.core.WorkbenchCorePlugin: Changed instanceLocation to: file:/home/emre/bin/carrot2-workbench-3.9.4/workspace/
2015-01-30 12:14:57,687 INFO  org.carrot2.util.xslt.TemplatesPool: XSLT transformer factory: com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f556c1212a1, pid=5578, tid=140007033534208
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b17) (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6c2a1]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x11
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/emre/bin/hs_err_pid5578.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

And it got stack on the start-up screen, waiting forever.

Any ideas how I can fix this and run the workbench?

Comment: Apparently this is about http://issues.carrot2.org/browse/CARROT-1058 (underlying framework's bug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is about http://issues.carrot2.org/browse/CARROT-1058 (underlying framework's bug). [According to core developers](http://carrot2-users-and-developers-forum.607571.n2.nabble.com/Can-t-run-Carrot2-Document-Clustering-Workbench-for-64-bit-Linux-version-3-9-4-on-my-Ubuntu-14-04-tp7578686p7578687.html), the options are limited to running the Carrot2 Workbench in a virtual machine with an older Ubuntu (or on Windows / MacOS).

Answer (score 0):

The actual Snapshot should solve the problem: http://download.carrot2.org/head/3.10.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Thanks for keeping an eye and informing me! :)